# Filter Firestore database with two Spinner to RecyclerView

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, spinner

I am making a blood bank application with firestore database.
i want to get my data with two spinners for correct blood group and location of person  who using my application. i used many method to dio this thing,but i failed everytime. this time you want fix it for the society.

and i made a index for that in my firestoew databse
my code is

```
public class ListActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {

    public Dialog dialog;
    Spinner bloodg,localbodyg;
    Context context;
    TextView sk;

    private FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance ( );
    private CollectionReference noteBokkRef = db.collection ("users");



    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    public NoteAdapter adapter;
    public String name1,place1,number1,blood1,location1;
  public   String bld;
  public   String lclbdy;
    public String group1;
    public String munci;

    Button load;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate (savedInstanceState);
        setContentView (R.layout.activity_list);

        overridePendingTransition( R.anim.fui_slide_in_right, R.anim.fui_slide_out_left );

        recyclerView=findViewById (R.id.recyclerview);
        recyclerView.setVisibility (View.INVISIBLE);

         load=findViewById (R.id.load);
         bloodg=findViewById (R.id.bloodg);
         localbodyg=findViewById (R.id.localbodyg);



        final ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter1=ArrayAdapter.createFromResource (this, R.array.blood_groups, R.layout.spinner_item);
        adapter1.setDropDownViewResource (android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        bloodg.setAdapter (adapter1);
        bloodg.setOnItemSelectedListener (this);

        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence>adapter2=ArrayAdapter.createFromResource (this, R.array.muncipality, R.layout.spinner_item);
        adapter2.setDropDownViewResource (android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        localbodyg.setAdapter (adapter2);
        localbodyg.setOnItemSelectedListener (this);


        load.setOnClickListener (new View.OnClickListener ( ) {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                recyclerView.setVisibility (View.VISIBLE);
                Toast.makeText (ListActivity.this,bld +lclbdy,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show ();
            }
        });


        setUpRecyclerView ( );


    }

    public void setUpRecyclerView() {


        String blood = bloodg.getSelectedItem().toString();
        String localbody = localbodyg.getSelectedItem().toString();

        Query query=db.collection ("users")
                .whereEqualTo ("bloodgroup",bloodg.getSelectedItem ().toString ())
                .whereEqualTo ("muncipality",localbodyg.getSelectedItem ().toString ())
                .orderBy ("name",Query.Direction.ASCENDING);
        FirestoreRecyclerOptions<Note>options=new FirestoreRecyclerOptions.Builder<Note> ()
                .setQuery (query,Note.class).build ();
        FirebaseFirestoreSettings settings=new FirebaseFirestoreSettings .Builder ()
                .setPersistenceEnabled (false)

                .build ();
        adapter=new NoteAdapter (options);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize (true);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager (new LinearLayoutManager (this));
        recyclerView.setAdapter (adapter);

        adapter.setOnItemClickListener (new NoteAdapter.OnItemClickListener ( ) {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(Note note, int position) {
                String number=note.getNumber ();
                String name=note.getName ();
                String place=note.getPlace ();
                String location=note.getMuncipality ();
                String blood=note.getBloodgroup ();
                name1=name;
                place1=place;
                location1=location;
                blood1=blood;
                number1=number;

                startDialog();
            }


        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart ( );
        adapter.startListening ();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop ( );
        adapter.stopListening ();
    }

    private void startDialog() {
        dialog = new Dialog(this);
        dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.custompopup);
        dialog.show();


        TextView tv_message = (TextView) dialog .findViewById(R.id.txtclose);
        TextView name=dialog.findViewById (R.id.name2);
        name.setText (name1);
        TextView place=dialog.findViewById (R.id.place);
        place.setText (place1);
        TextView localbody=dialog.findViewById (R.id.location);
        localbody.setText (location1);
        TextView blood=dialog.findViewById (R.id.blood);
        blood.setText (blood1);
        TextView number=dialog.findViewById (R.id.number);
        number.setText (number1);

        Button call = (Button)dialog.findViewById(R.id.call);
        call.setOnClickListener (new View.OnClickListener ( ) {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL, Uri.parse("tel:" + number1));
                startActivity(intent);

            }
        });
        Button share=dialog.findViewById (R.id.share);
        share.setOnClickListener (new View.OnClickListener ( ) {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent shareIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                shareIntent.setType("text/plain");
                shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,name1+"\n"+blood1+"\n"+place1+"\n"+location1+"\n"+number1+"\n");
                shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "The title");
                startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, "Share..."));
            }
        });


        Button chat=dialog.findViewById (R.id.whatsapp);
        chat.setOnClickListener (new View.OnClickListener ( ) {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Uri uri=Uri.parse ("smsto:"+number1);
                Intent intent=new Intent (Intent.ACTION_SENDTO, uri);
                intent.setPackage ("com.whatsapp");
                intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,"Your score and Some extra text");
                intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "The title");
                startActivity (intent);
            }
        });



        tv_message.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });


    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater ().inflate (R.menu.menu1,menu);
        MenuItem item=menu.findItem (R.id.search);

        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu (menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected (item);
    }



    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        if(parent.getId() == R.id.bloodg)
        {
            String group=parent.getItemAtPosition (position).toString ();
            if (position!=0){
                Toast.makeText (parent.getContext (),group,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show ();}
            bld=group;
        }
        else if(parent.getId() == R.id.localbodyg)
        {
            String muncipality=parent.getItemAtPosition (position).toString ();
            if (position!=0){
                Toast.makeText (parent.getContext (),muncipality,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show ();}
            lclbdy=muncipality;        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

    }



    public void call(View view) {
    }
}
```

Database structure:

[image]

Comment: What exactly in this code doesn't work the way you expect?

Comment: @AlexMamo the database not filtering with the value of spinner.(whereEqualTo ("bloodgroup",bloodg.getSelectedItem ().toString ()))

but if we add a value like A+ in coding it works

Comment: Please add your database structure as a JSON file or at least a screenshot. Please also provide the value of `bloodg.getSelectedItem ().toString ()`.

Comment: @AlexMamo [link](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1M6XMRK37jix4uKrZlAzUvpkEuYZQgYfe)

Comment: @AlexMamo [link](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1M6XMRK37jix4uKrZlAzUvpkEuYZQgYfe) this is my database's screen shot

Comment: Please also provide the value of `bloodg.getSelectedItem ().toString ()`.

Comment: @AlexMamo user will select the value from the spinner.
i can't predict that

Comment: @AlexMamo sir please help